# Display all taxonomy terms's ids associated with nodes in a view

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I need to display the term ids of each node under its title in a view.

I can do similar display by adding node: title and node: all taxonomy terms. But I just want to display tid's instead of term names.

My view result should look like this:

title: Node title 1

tids: 1, 2, 4

title: Node title 2

tids: 3, 5, 6

Is there a way to alter or add a views field for this?

Also in general, how are fields that is available to the views constructed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add field "All taxonomy terms". Then check the "rewrite output of this field" box, and in the rewrite box enter the token `[term_node_tid-tid]`.

Comment: Thanks beth, but when i do this, it will display the same node for each term. "All taxonomy terms" field is special that it aggregates all terms of a node and displays all of them in the same row as a list, or comma separated.

Comment: If you exclude node title from display and then use it as a grouping field, you'll get a list of all the TIDs underneath. You can then use CSS to put them all on the same line.

Comment: I found a much better solution and amended my answer.

Comment: There is no such field named "terms on node" as far as I know. Can you expand your answer? Do you add relationships? Which table you are using to create your view (node, term, etc)?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, the name is "All taxonomy terms". This can be used either with a node-based view, or a term-based view via a "nodes with term" relationship.

Comment: I never noticed that field comes with different replacement tokens :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a crazy thing to hide deep down in the rewrite output field.

Comment: I never noticed this field, this solution saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Addition to the @beth 's answer:

"all taxonomy terms" field apparently provides multiple replacement tokens:

[term_node_tid] == Content: All taxonomy terms
[term_node_tid-tid] == The taxonomy term ID for the term.
[term_node_tid-name] == The taxonomy term name for the term.
[term_node_tid-vocabulary-machine-name] == The machine name for the vocabulary the term belongs to.
[term_node_tid-vocabulary] == The name for the vocabulary the term belongs to.

Hidden gem :) I wonder how many other fields come with similar behavior..